# Is it a good practice to use printf and fprintf in the same codeblock?

Tags: c, file, conventions

I remember hearing that its a bad practice to use `printf()` and `fprintf()` functions in the same code block.

```
fprintf(stdout, "The first line,\n");  
printf("The second line,\n");
```

Or simply,

```
fprintf(somefile, "Its a file");
printf("Some text");
```

I, as a result, always use `fprintf()` and `fgets()` for input and output. Is it misconception of mine?

Comment: Right or wrong depends on the larger code context.  It is likely a weak practice, yet exceptions exists.

Comment: I guess it's better to not mix `fprintf` and `printf` for stdout as it will hinder readability, choose one or the other. You may also check the new C11 `printf_s` and `fprintf_s` with safety check and 'better' unicode support.

Comment: This is the first time I have heard any suggestion of it being bad practice in 39 years of C programming. I'm not saying that there are no people who think it is bad practice, but they would have to provide a good rationale.

Comment: The first and the second code snippets are entirely different. The first one is somewhat pointless just use `printf(x)` instead of `fprintf(stdout, x);`, both do exactly the same thing. In the second code snippet you print `"Its a file"` into a file and then you print `"Some text"` to stdout, there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Zilog80: Note `printf_s` and friends are an optional part of C11, and AFAIK the only major implementation that has chosen to adopt them is MSVC.  So using these "standard" features will severely limit portability.

Comment: @NateEldredge Good point, the lack of implementation worth to be mentioned.  In fact, 'safe' `printf_s` isn't a wise choice regarding that.

Answer (score 1):

It has no effect on the program semantics (because `printf` is defined to do the same as `fprintf` with `stdout` interposed), and a compiler should treat `printf(…)` and `fprintf(stdout, …)` identically.<sup>1</sup>

Perhaps there could be some effects if the compiler cannot see that `somefile` is `stdout` when `fprintf(somefile, "Its a file");` is used. For example, during optimization, the compiler might optimize `fprintf(somefile, "Its a file"); printf("Some text");` to `fputs("Its a fileSome text", stdout);` if it knows `somefile` is `stdout`. Obviously, if it does not know `somefile` is `stdout`, it cannot make this optimization.

Outside of these concerns, the question is just one of human behavior—will one be more confusing to human readers or more prone to editing errors or other errors? My evaluation would be these effects are largely slight in this case, but it would be nice to adopt a uniform style, such as only use `fprintf(stdout, …)` if there is some reason to emphasize `stdout` or to make the code flexible for edits that will change it to another stream.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Technically, the C standard allows compilers to do different things with `printf(…)` and `fprintf(stdout, …)` as long as the observable behavior satisfies the rules, but it also allows compilers to do different things depending on whether the current line number is even or odd, and good compilers do not.

Answer (score 1):

Style questions like this one tend to be subjective and fodder for unproductive debate.

I would say that

```
fprintf(stdout, "The first line,\n");  
printf("The second line,\n");
```

is poor style.  It's distracting and potentially confusing.  It will work, but it might give a later reader the wrong impression, perhaps suggesting an error.  It would be sort of like Randomly capitalizing Words aNd lEtteRs iN wORds.

If you're writing both to stdout and a file, then code like

```
fprintf(somefile, "Its a file");
printf("Some text");
```

is perfectly fine.  I can't imagine why anyone would object to this.

Earlier in my C programming career, I had decided that it was poor style to mix `printf` with other output functions.  So I would have discouraged

```
printf("Part of the first line");  
if(condition) printf(", and the rest");
putchar('\n');
```

and I would have preferred

```
printf("Part of the first line");  
if(condition) printf(", and the rest");
printf("\n");
```

I had a very specific reason for this preference, but it wasn't a very good reason, and I've abandoned it.  (Also mixing `printf` and `putchar` wasn't what you were asking about anyway.)